# Resend SMS code with Django Two-factor Authentication

Tags: django, twilio, two-factor-authentication

I'm using Django with django-two-factor-auth for my web application. I can now send SMS via Twilio and verify it, but I haven't figured out how to resend the SMS code when I need i.e. click on "Didn't received your code? Resend!".

I have read through [django-two-factor-auth docs](http://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/index.html) but couldn't find any info about implementing this.

Do I need to configure django-two-factor-auth somehow, or customize the lib (which is what I don't really prefer to do) ?

Could you please help me? Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not possible with this package. However feel free to request this issue on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/issues).

Another possibility is to implement this yourself. The token is sent when the wizard page named [`token` is rendered](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/blob/76866dd310903b3a34526becaa0a5012dea7debe/two_factor/views/core.py#L142-L149). Your template would need to submit a POST to the login view, requesting the same page. The button should look similar to the [request backup token](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/blob/76866dd310903b3a34526becaa0a5012dea7debe/two_factor/templates/two_factor/core/login.html#L36-L37), so (untested) something like this:

```
    <button name="challenge_device" value="{{ device.persistent_id }}"
            class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="submit">Resend token</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @bouke. I'm using that work-around method :grinning:. Things work well, but it will be nice if you can add that